# Nunit Test run is freezed for large test case set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, resharper

Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.4

Resharper Version 2020.3.2

Nunit 3.13.1

if I wasn't wrong, i should be using the test runner from Resharper.

I put my test code below. It has no logic but creating a large test case set.
The test runner just freeze for a really long time (as you can see at screendump) and only start running test after 20-30 mins wait.

In actual development, for the sake of 95%+ unit test coverage, we do have some test case that has more than 80,000 cases that cannot be split or remove.
Is there any other alternative way to make the test run work ?

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test_LargeTestCaseSet
{
    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> LargeTestCases()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(i);
        }
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(LargeTestCases))]
    public void LargeTest(int i)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(i, i);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you can do it, it's helpful to respondents if you can report whether the same error occurs under a simple batch run using NUni3-console or NUnitLite. That also helps you in pulling useful answers, because it clarifies whether you actually need help from people with resharper knowlege or nunit knowledge.

Comment: @Charlie Look like the same behaviour only happened in VS/Resharper combination as i don't see the similar behaviour in Teamcity test run.

Comment: Ah well... thanks for checking. Not one I can answer then. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is! Do not declare your test as 100k separate test-cases. Obviously, it would not work well with UI that has a visual representation for each individual test-case.
Instead, just write the loop inside of the test method itself. Use `Assert.Multiple` if you want all of "test-cases" to run on each execution of the test. If knowing the first encountered failure is enough, simple `Assert.XXX` would suffice.